# VB.Net Get characters from after certain words

Tags: string, vb.net, split

I'm trying to 'extract' a number from a string by using the following simple code to split the string at `:` and then just use the first few characters of the result. However the actual real world string contains two numbers preceded by a `:`, I only want one of these pulled from the string but this is causing me some problems. I'm trying to extract the number from the following part of the string: `Our Ref: 200018` but the split function only seems to support one character to split from. In the real world this number changes a lot, but remains the same 8 characters in length.

How can I extract only the number from `Our Ref: 200018` *without* the `Your Ref: 265845` getting mixed up with it in the code?

```
Dim sOutput As String = "This is an example string Our Ref: 200018 Your Ref: 265845 did this work?"
Dim word As String = sOutput
Dim wordArr As String() = word.Split(":")
MsgBox("Result: " & wordArr(1).ToString)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Regex`:

```
Dim sOutput As String = "This is an example string Our Ref: 200018 Your Ref: 265845 did this work?"
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(sOutput, "\bOur Ref\b\:\s*(\d+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

If m.Success = True Then 'Match found.
    Dim Ref As Integer = Integer.Parse(m.Groups(1).Value)
    MessageBox.Show(Ref)
End If
```

Imports required:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

This code is case-insensitive so it'll match for instance `oUr rEF` or `OUR REF` (etc.) as well.

**Online test: http://ideone.com/DetTxq**

The pattern explained:

```
\bOur Ref\b\:\s*(\d+)

\b         =>  Word boundary, means that it should match whole words (i.e. only "Our Ref" and not "Your Ref", etc.).
Our Ref    =>  Match the words "Our Ref".
\:         =>  Match a colon.
\s*        =>  Match zero or more spaces.
(          =>  Start of match group.
    \d+    =>  Match one or more numerical characters.
)          =>  End of match group.
```

Match groups are "sub-matches" which's values can be accessed via `Match.Groups(<group index>).Value`. Group index 0 is the entire match.

Read more:

- [**`Regex` class - MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [**`Match.Groups` property - MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [**Regular Expressions Language - Quick Reference - MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, one of the best answered, most detailed and helpful answers I've ever had. Your answer has proved very useful and you've helped me to better understand Regex, as I'm a self-taught coder. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3516240 : Glad I could help and that my answer was to your satisfaction! Funny coincidence: I am self-taught as well. :)

Comment: @user3516240 : I just noticed this'll match `Your Ref:` as well if it comes before `Our Ref:`. I have edited my answer to fix so that it'll match `Our Ref:` _**only**_.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim sOutput As String = "This is an example string Our Ref: 200018 Your Ref: 265845 did this work?"
Dim word As String() = New String() {"Our Ref: "} 
Dim wordArr As String() = sOutput.Split(word,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

And then just take the 8 first Chars from the substring from example:

```
Dim str As String = wordArr(1).Substring(0,7)
```

More Info: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why are you using `String.Join`? `wordArr(1)` is a single string, not an array.

Comment: You're right. Here can be used directly `Dim str As String = wordArr(1).Substring(0,7)`. Already edited :)